# WatchOS 3 sharing information and actions between interfaces

Tags: watchos-3, wkinterfacecontroller

I have a table on my main watch interface. Upon user selection, a 2nd interface will show and display more details about the user picked item.

I'm thinking about adding a button to this 2nd interface, so when user clicked on this button, the watch will send the picked item's information to the pair iPhone through WatchConnectivity.

The problem is how can this button-click event on the 2nd interface trigger the WCSession action on the 1st main interface?

Thank you!
Paul

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to create delegate method in the class you manages WCSession and you would be able to interact using WatchConnectivity at any part of your watchOS app. Do not bound the code that manages WCSession with any interface.